# Add Pictures to QuickPart Autotext with OpenXML SDK 2.5

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I try to add pictures in a autotext with the openxml sdk, the problem now is that i can add the autotexts but the pictures cannot currently be displayed. That has something to do with the relationship id´s, but when i try to add the picture with the same id from the original template, i get the error that the current id is already in use.

to add the pictures i try the following code:

```
foreach (DocumentBinaryPart relatedDocumentPart in AutotextContainer.RelatedDocumentParts.Where(x => x.Type == "ImagePart"))
     {
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        ImagePart imagePart = glossaryDocument.AddImagePart(relatedDocumentPart.ImageType, relatedDocumentPart.relationshipid);

        using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(relatedDocumentPart.Data))
        {
           imagePart.FeedData(stream);
        }
mainDocumentPart.GlossaryDocumentPart.GlossaryDocument.Save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think after the `Save()` you should call the `Close()` method.  That should hopefully fix it.